# How to get square root in Rust 0.13.0?

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

In 0.13.0-nightly the following code won't compile:

```
fn main() {
    let a = (10.5f64).sqrt();
}
```

I get the error:

```
error: type `f64` does not implement any method in scope named `sqrt`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sqrt` method is in the [`std::num::Float`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/num/trait.Float.html#tymethod.sqrt) trait, so you need to `use` it:

```
use std::num::Float;

fn main() {
    let a = (10.5f64).sqrt();
    println!("{}", a);
}
```

prints

```
3.24037
```

[Demo](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Anum%3A%3AFloat%3B%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20%2810.5f64%29.sqrt%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20a%29%3B%0A%7D)